# How to add whitespace in between two string in C

Tags: c, string

I am making strcat version of my own in C, but I am not able to add whitespace in between the concatenated words.
ps: Searched a lot got no appropriate answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int xstrlen(char *a)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*a != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        a++;
    }
    return count;
}
void xstrcpy(char *a, char *b, char *c)
{
    while (*b != '\0')
    {
        *a++ = *b;
        *b++;
    }
    while (*c != '\0')
    {
        *a++ = *c;
        *c++;
    }
    *a = '\0';
}
void xstrcat(char *a, char *b)
{
    xstrcpy(a, a, b);
}
int main()
{
    char src[20], tar[20];
    puts("First Name");
    gets(src);
    puts("Last Name");
    gets(tar);
    printf("Executing...\n");
    xstrcat(src, tar);
    printf("Full Name - %s", src);

    printf("\nEnter any Key to exit...");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

tried adding *a = ' ' between two while loops in xstrcpy, but it did not work.

Comment: `*a++ = ' ';` Also `*b++;` and `*c++;` should be `b++;` and `c++;`, and in fact you could simply do `*a++ = *b++;` and `*a++ = *c++;` and delete the lines that increment `b` and `c`.

Comment: *Never* use `gets`

Comment: If '`xstrcat` is correct, you can first concatenate a space string `" "` onto `src` and then `tar`.

Answer (score 2):

It could be as easy as

```
        *a++=' ';
```

Complete Code:

```
void xstrcpy(char *a, char *b, char *c)
{
    while (*b != '\0')
    {
        *a++ = *b++;
    }

    *a++=' ';

    while (*c != '\0')
    {
        *a++ = *c++;
    }
    *a = '\0';
}
```